# SQLite query not working in cronjob(Production)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, cron

I have a sqlite query written in python:
dibbs5.py

```
cursor.executemany ( """
INSERT INTO dibbs_spider_dibbs_fields(hash,nsn,nomenclature,technical_documents,solicitation,
status,purchase_request,issued,return_by,file)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
""" , records )
```

This works fine in local, in production when I execute this from terminal, it executes. But when I schedule this in cronjob, it shows the error:

```
 cursor.executemany ( """
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dibbs_spider_dibbs_fields
```

There is a table name `dibbs_spider_dibbs_fields`

Crontab:

```
31 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/manage.py makemigrations > /root/spider/migration.log 2>&1
32 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/manage.py migrate > /root/spider/migration2.log 2>&1
33 09 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/dibbs5.py > /root/spider/dibbserorr3.log 2>&1
```

Comment: can you display the logs?

Comment: Check the logs in the error

Comment: also display your migration logs, it seems crontab is not migrating properly

Comment: You'll need to add more information. No one can guess what your scripts contain, etc. And why are you running the migrations in a cron job?

Comment: check if `* * * * * ls /path/to/database.db > /dev/pts/0` (or whatever `tty` you are in) works. if so, then check if `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 -c "from sqlite3 import connect as c;db=c('/path/to/database.db');dbc=db.cursor();r=dbc.execute('select name from sqlite_schema where type=\'table\';').fetchone();print('tables:',r)" > /dev/pts/0` shows the list of tables. probably not even the first will work. sqlite3 creates a new file if not found, and it is probably not finding the table because it is using a new database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the `dibbs5.py` using `root` in the production terminal? Does it work? If Yes, please change the crontab using this command

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

```
31 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/manage.py makemigrations > /root/spider/migration.log 2>&1
32 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/manage.py migrate > /root/spider/migration2.log 2>&1
33 09 * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python3 /root/spider/dibbs5.py > /root/spider/dibbserorr3.log 2>&1
```

I have a feeling that you are not editing crontab for `root`.  The program that you encountered is because the table is absent from the file as environmental variable(s) were not correct setup, resulting in accessing wrong file.